# Update Redux form state with File object data via Change action creator

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I wonder if anyone has some idea to update File object data to redux form states via Change action creator?
According to the docs, value for payload would accept any.

current behavior: can not update redux-formstate with the File object via Change action creator, and the payload is empty.

expected behavior: can update redux-formstate with File object via Change action creator

[image]

https://redux-form.com/7.0.0/docs/api/props.md/#-code-change-field-string-value-any-function-code-

version: 7.0.4